# Combine two queries with functions and average in each

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that performs a calculation on 2 columns (col1 and col2) and then does the average of the results based on a given criteria (time = week1 and week2) and groups them based on another criteria (ID).

It looks like that:

```
SELECT subquery1.[ID], Avg (Param1) as Avg_Param1 
FROM
(
SELECT [Table1].[ID], [Table1].Time, [col1]/40)/[col2] AS Param1 
FROM Table1
) AS subquery1
WHERE (subQuery1.Time = 'week 1' or subquery1.Time = 'Week 2')
Group By subquery1.[ID]
;
```

Now I would like in the same query to create a column called Avg_param2 were the were criteria is let say "week 5" and "week 6".

I can do that in a second query and then join them, but how could I do that in one shot?

Comment: By using the IIf() function to send the appropriate rows to the column you want. Send a NULL to have it ignore the row in the average calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  [Table1].[ID],  
       AVG(IIF( [Table1].Time IN ('week 1','Week 2') , [col1]/40/[col2] , NULL)) AS Avg_Param1 ,  
       AVG(IIF( [Table1].Time IN ('week 5','Week 6') , [col1]/40/[col2] , NULL))  AS Avg_Param2 
FROM [Table1]
Group By [Table1].[ID]
```

Comment: Had to add a ) after NULL) but it worked ! Thanks a lot !